# React Typescript - What's the difference between import @types/react and import react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import

I am a beginner with react (even tho I did some ReactJs already) and  I am today trying to create a simple app using `TypeScript (instead of pure Javascript)`.

However, when running npm start, I found an issue that I understand, but I can't understand why it is an issue.

Let say we have this code (main.tsx):

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Can you explain to me clearly what is the difference with

```
import * as React from '@types/react';
```

In my package.json I have `"@types/react": "^16.9.2"` and I don't have `react`, so the issue is quite logic that the package couldn't be found. But then what's the difference between these two imports?

Also, I can't even import `@types/react`, I can only install it

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones with `@types` prefix are type declaration packages, more info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html).

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the answer. Then I would have a second question: `When do I know that I need the @types/ version of a package?`

Comment: @Emixam23: If you don't get "intellisense/code completion" when using a library you can try searching for/installing the corresponding `@types package`. You can search using  `npm search @types/package_name` or http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/. So you don't need the `@types package`, but it's helpful.

Comment: I'm kind of in the same boat sure old timers know the difference.  Emixam23 gave a great answer, just want to add as Typescript is getting adopted more, some libraries are now including the types in the library for you.  Couldn't find the  types  file for Axios, simply because they rock!  They have already provided the types,  no need for an extra types  file.

Just thinking this will be common for noobs like myself getting up to speed.  Think the other tip given, autocomplete and seeing type related errors, you see them, you have all you need :)